# How to programatically submit/send multiple files using jquery-file-upload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-file-upload, blueimp

There's quite a lot of options for this plugin (jquery-file-upload) and the docs look good, but I'm still a bit confused. I have a form that looks like:

```
<form id="fileupload" action="/file-upload" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-buttons">
    <span id="add-files-wrap">
        <span>Add Files</span>
        <input id="add-files-btn" type="file" name="files[]" multiple>
    </span>
    <button id="upload-btn" type="button" onclick="uploadFiles()" class="btn-disabled">
        <span>Start Upload</span>
    </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When a file or files get added, the `add` callback in the fileupload intialiser is triggered:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
url: '/file-upload',
sequentialUploads: true,
add: function(e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function(idx, file) {
            MY_FILES.push(file);
        }
    }
});
```

Then when the upload button from the form is clicked:

```
function uploadFiles() {
for (var i=0; i<MY_FILES.length; i++) {
        // Submit the file - how ???
    }
}
```

I'd like to submit/send each file one at a time, using separate requests for each. I know I could do `fileupload('send', {files: MY_FILES})` but I'd like to have a callback that's triggered for every successful response from the request. I'm a bit confused with all the callback options in the docs.

**Edit:**
Answered my own question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After looking through the docs some more, I ended up doing something like this:

```
function uploadFiles() {
    uploadFile( FILES.pop() );
}

function uploadFile(file) {
    if (file == null) {
        console.log("Finished processing files.");
        return;
    }
    $('#fileupload').fileupload('send', {files: [file]})
    .success(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("Success...");
        uploadFile( FILES.pop() );
    })
    .error(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log("Error...");
    })
    .complete(function (result, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        console.log("Complete...");
    });
}
```

This works fine.